# jQuery dataTables : Why is sAjaxSource not taking my path?

Tags: jquery, datatables, filepath

The default path is like this:

```
"sAjaxSource": "http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/scripts/jsonp.php",
    "fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "url": sUrl,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback,
            "dataType": "jsonp",
            "cache": false
        } );
    }
```

But when I change it to this:

```
`"sAjaxSource": "/libclient_final/library/viewtarrif.php",
    "fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "url": sUrl,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback,
            "dataType": "jsonp",
            "cache": false
        } );
    }`
```

the data is not coming back and the table header and footer collapse

Comment: How your `viewtarrif.php` return's json ?

Comment: yes it is. both also giving same out put...